# What do we do with this Cleric Quicken Spells question?

Tags: discussion, questions

[What options are available for a Cleric casting multiple spells per round?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/7605/1204)

This old question is about a cleric who wants to speed up his casting of divine spells. By our current standards for asking and answering, answers should respond to that exact situation and offer options which help clerics speed up divine spellcasting.

However, it's also a textbook case of a user asking about their specific situation [in very broad terms to be useful](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/should-i-use-a-narrow-system-tag-or-go-broad-if-possible-and-use-system-agnosti). In this case, they expanded the question to ask for all options to speeding up *every* kind of spell. That really is what happened; they even considered it a mistake to mention they were a cleric:

> P.S. I see a lot of requests for more information on my character. I was hoping to create a question that more people would find useful (I guess I shouldn't have mentioned that I am a cleric either ;-) ).

### The answers are messy as a result.

Most go into Cleric specifics without worrying about stuff for any other casters. Others mention things that explicitly only speed up *arcane* spell casting, which whilst useful is irrelevant to a cleric.

*Hey I Can Chan* then posted [this excellent compilation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/31272/1204) of effects that speed up spellcasting, but a great number are completely irrelevant to clerics.

By our current standards this is all over the place. They're answering two different situations ("What things speed up spells?" and "What things speed up *cleric* spells?") because of how the question was asked.

### What do we do?

Do we leave this messed up?

Do we somehow split the answers into a canon question for speeding up Divine casting and a canon question for speeding up anything-casting?

Comment: I've closed it as too broad.

Comment: I reopened it and only mildly edited my answer - this is actually a good question with relevant answers.

Comment: My apologies. I got distracted by the question's title and minimized the question's text. Problem solved?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Considering the edits to the question and your answer and the fact this meta topic was a false alarm on a question that was not actually that bad, yes I think so.

Answer (score 3):

The question has been edited to be more narrow, with cleric and level, so I don't think closing the question's appropriate.  Stuff like this isn't complicated and doesn't require meta questions - a comment on the question saying "no, we like questions specific, thanks" and then comments on far afield answers saying "yes but what about sixth level clerics" suffice.

He edited that information in 4 hours after asking the question back in 2011, so I find it hard to fault the questioner much here.

Comment: I asked it on meta since it's so old there's not much point commenting on the question or most answers. Beside that though, I just realised it isn't as messy as I thought. :/ It's only _Hey I Can Chan_'s answer providing a bunch of not-Cleric stuff and your answer mentioning a couple of non-Divine things. That means the answers are mostly on target for a question about a level 6 Cleric.