# For general 'universe' questions, should we keep a generic 'universe' tag or tag all the various systems available for the game?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing, game-systems

This question was spurred by an edit to this question: [How can I avoid plot pitfalls that are common to the Star Trek franchise?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17196/avoiding-plot-pitfalls-in-star-trek-rpg) which consisted solely in adding the [star-trek-fasa](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-fasa) tag.

While I see why this tag was added, the OP said in a comment in one of the answers that they are using FASA's rules, the question in itself is completely system-agnostic, and would apply to every version of the Star Trek RPG (Decipher, LUG and the new Star Trek Adventures that was released last year).

I feel that leaving the [star-trek-fasa](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-fasa) tag alone has a potential to be misleading, but I'm not sure whether we should add all the system tags, currently [star-trek-decipher](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-decipher) and [star-trek-adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-adventures), or remove the [star-trek-fasa](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-fasa) and keep only the generic [star-trek](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek).

What does the community think?

Note: In my opinion, the potential duplicate isn't really about the same problem. The duplicate was about someone needing advice on how to design pirate adventure in D&D4 and wondering if they should broaden their question since you can have pirate adventures in other games. Here, the question is about problems that are very specific to the Star Trek universe (I don't know many other games with transporters, for example), but not tied to a specific system since those problems can crop up in any version of the Star Trek RPG.

Comment: Related: [Should we be encouraging askers to remove system tags if their question is relevant to a broader category?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3501/should-we-be-encouraging-askers-to-remove-system-tags-if-their-question-is-relev), [Should I use a narrow system tag, or use a broader tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/should-i-use-a-narrow-system-tag-or-use-a-broader-tag)

Answer (score 6):

### Sometimes the rules are there to help.

Knowing the system, and even the version, is important to properly answer questions that might seem system-agnostic.

Let's suppose the Modiphius Star Trek system had a sidebar talking about ways to work around or with the common plot spackles of the show, like transporter abuse or warp drive tinkering, using mechanics specific to the Modiphius 2d20 engine. Even if those exist, how useful are they to someone playing FASA Star Trek, without additional work on someone's part to bridge the gap?

Similarly, if that guidance exists somewhere in the body of rules and discussion for FASA Star Trek, it's not too helpful for someone to just say "nothing helpful from Modiphius on it, here's my house rules" because that can easily be read as: there's nothing helpful out there, full stop.

So on this question, the two tags [star-trek](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) and [star-trek-fasa](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-fasa) are both useful - the problem is fairly universal to plotting in Star Trek, so it's open to anybody with expertise in a Star Trek RPG. But if the problem is solved in another Star Trek system, then people who know that will also know they need to express it in terms useful to someone playing FASA Star Trek.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what is your answer to my question. Given that the original question is, from my point of view, an RP question that applies to Star Trek in general, and not a rule question that applies to a specific system, should we just keep the tags as simply the generic [Star-Trek] or put all the tags for every different versions of Star Trek systems?

Comment: Depending on the system it may not be just an RP question. For a completely made-up example: "How do I stop my PCs from casually messing with the warp core?" "Messing with the warp core is a Class VI Grievous Obstacle that costs 5 Hamdingers to even attempt! If you have PCs who can clear that kind of hurdle they've earned the right to mess with the warp core."

Comment: @Sava This is saying that there’s third option—add just the tag of the game actually involved—and making a case for adding just that one tag.