# Are system tags only for directly rules-related questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84830/how-to-encourage-players-to-work-better-as-a-team) question is tagged with [pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder). [This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29341) suggested edit removes the tag, and replaces it with [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic), on the grounds that the question does not directly concern the pathfinder rules. However, the asker in question is playing pathfinder.

**Is the [pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder) tag only appropriate when the question directly concerns the rules of pathfinder, or should it be used whenever the asker wants a solution for a pathfinder game?**

**Is this the case for all system tags?**

*This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/should-i-use-a-narrow-system-tag-or-go-broad-if-possible-and-use-system-agnosti), as it is asking specifically whether a requirement of system tags is that the question must directly concern the rules of the system.*

Comment: possible duplicate: [Should I use a system tag...?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3010/23970)

Comment: Related: [Can I edit a question to be more generic?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6387/23970)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

System tags are for more than just rules, and we're supposed to be providing solutions to the real problems folks are facing. Leave the tag.

Most game systems have playstyle assumptions and table etiquette built into them: the kind of stories being told, the relationship between GM and players, the interaction between PCs in the group, and much more.

If the question can be answered in a way that doesn't rely on Pathfinder assumptions, that's great! But it doesn't make the question any less about how to encourage teamwork in a Pathfinder game, and by removing that information we risk losing out on PF-specific answers (I can't imagine any, but one thing this site has taught me is that the RPG world is far broader than my mind can encompass or even predict).

(Experience has shown that attempts to artificially broaden a question's scope usually make answers vague and hand-wavy, of little use to anyone. Good answers to specific questions explain themselves so that others in similar situations also find them useful.)

Comment: Thanks - I have reverted the edit by replacing the pathfinder tag. I have however left the system agnostic tag there.

Comment: @Ladifas Relevant then: [Does the \[system-agnostic\] tag conflict with system specific tags?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3024)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That Q&A looks out of date; I don’t see [system-agnostic] really used as described in the first three cases.

Comment: @KRyan Yeah, you have a point. I don't see most of those uses anymore. I guess they're still more-or-less valid uses of the tag, but it overall doesn't seem to be used as often today as it used to be; it seems more often just left off so that some non-game tag is the primary tag.