# Should I have removed the [pathfinder-2e] tag from this question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, questions

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196638/as-a-dm-how-can-i-address-players-frustration-with-in-game-decision-making) was asked.

When I read it, it seemed to be a general one, and most of the advice was system agnostic, so I removed the [pathfinder-2e] tag and added the [system-agnostic] tag.

But, then I noticed some answers actually did include PF2E-specific solutions, and one person edited their answer to add a "Note: This question was originally about Pathfinder..." disclaimer. This indicated to me that I had disrupted an equilibrium, which (in stable ecosystems) is generally harmful.

Sub-question: If the opposite solution was better - editing the question to specify edition, but possibly causing people who don't care about PF to quickly parse the question as less useful - should implicit context be made explicit in edits?

Comment: From our FAQ: [Should I use a narrow system tag, or use a broader tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/should-i-use-a-narrow-system-tag-or-use-a-broader-tag)

Comment: Another potentially relevant FAQ: [How is the \[system-agnostic\] tag supposed to be used?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8833/33569)

Answer (score 9):

### I wouldn't have.

The tag text is:

> For questions that are **explicitly** not restricted to any one particular system or rules, where the **asker wants** solutions to the question that are not directly tied to a game's mechanics.

(Emphasis mine.)

Prior to your tag edit, the question was not "**explicitly** not restricted" (if you'll pardon the double negative) "to any one particular system."  It might have been implicitly not restricted (especially if the pf 2e tag had not been there) but it wasn't explicit.

And while there are many valid situations to edit a tag on someone else's question, doing so where the tag description itself defers to the asker intent does not seem to be one of those.

Comment: Indeed. If the querent wants, they can edit the tag in themselves. Otherwise, other users can ask whether the querent whether they're interested in system-agnostic answers (or can simply leave a system-agnostic answer, if nothing in the specific system contradicts that approach) – but others shouldn't simply edit the system information out of the post. As indicated by [ESCE's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/196668/33569), there is apparently a PF2e-specific approach that could be relevant to this situation, so the tag should probably stay on the question.

Comment: (Also, since system information often goes unstated in questions when it's indicated by a tag, system tags shouldn't be removed in general without somehow ensuring that that information is included in the body of the post.)

Answer (score 0):

### Slight balance to keep system

In general, **many** questions about player agency, problem players or GMs, and social contract are only minimally impacted by the actual game played, as long as the *type* of game matches. While the answer for Pathfinder might not differ too much from Dungeons and Dragons 3.5, as both can be classic dungeon crawlers. Likewise, an answer about Masks can be based on a profound knowledge of how to handle situations in other Apocalypse World settings.

**However** the game played can make the answer much better and have a huge impact on how to solve the question. There are nuances of playstyle and powers/equipment that inform answers.

Let me take one (very simplistic) example and just swap the game:

> We are stuck at a closed door and have nobody with lockpicks and skills, no heavy tools and can't hire someone else. How could we get out of this pickle and get in?

- If this was tagged with any classic dungeon crawler, the answers might list things like the disintegrate spell, knock/open lock.
- If this was Shadowrun, you might get answers to jus buy the tools at the next Fixer, especially explosives (grenades) or an automatic lockpick. Other options are to hijack a car and ram the wall because the walls are always weaker than the doors (duh!).
- In Exalted it would be just a chance to show off and kick in the door.
- In MAID the answer could be as simple as "get the key from master by spending favor".
- In a game of Rats, however, the answer could be "this is not the right way, come back again later!"

Comment: I think your example should be a less mechanical one. Mechanics will rather clearly vary game to game but with things like the question this Meta is about, that is less clear. I think an example more along those lines (perhaps even *the* one being asked about) would help improve this